# Tools to manage upgrade of heavily modified framework

Tags: php, mysql, testing, upgrade

I realize this question is a bit subjective and won't have a definitive answer but hopefully it's a question that can help others in the same situation.

I am running an extremely modified CMS (in this case xCart v4.1.8) and I am looking for the best tools/means to upgrade in an organized fashion.

We have added a boat load of functions, modules, new db tables, modified db tables, modules, etc.

We already use an SVN but with how heavily modified this CMS is I fear an SVN is far from enough.

I figure some sort of tool/script that will not only analyze code for differences but actually run through all of the functions, see what's passed and how it's manipulated then compare that with the other code in order to determine the differences.  If there's a way to integrate databases into the comparison that would be great too.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.  I imagine there would be tools that manage this and would prefer to not have to reinvent the wheel if at all possible.

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

Also for what it's worth the site we are upgrading consists of mainly PHP/MySQL and runs off Apache.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with SVN? Can you give a simple example where SVN does not suffice?

Comment: @Basti For instance if a function is called which is defined in a different file and the new function changes the type of parameter required.  Sure the might be evident in the file with the function definition in it but not so obvious on the file referencing the function.

Comment: I hardly believe that you can solve such problem syntactically, but who am I to spread pessimism. Good luck! ;-)

Comment: @Basti Bah, well any input as to how to handle this would be great.  Are you saying that an SVN should be able to handle this?  I just worry that with the upgrade we are making an SVN would not be as useful for this.  Perhaps there is some functionality within an SVN that might which would be great, I'm just hoping to be pointed in the right direction.  Regardless thank you for your time and your assistance. :)

Comment: Nono, SVN cannot do this. I'm saying that you shouldn't want this because it will probably not work, i.e. damage your code. Altering function calls because the function's signature has change is not a just syntactical change. It might look easy to you because you "know" what a function does, but it's really not if you scratch the "knowing"-part and just do it syntactical.

Comment: @Basti Thank you greatly for getting back to me so that I could confirm we were on the same page.  You're absolutely correct with what you just said which was why I was hoping there was a particular method to use for this scenario.  Regardless I appreciate your time and thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there are any tools that would analyse and merge code difference automatically.

It's been a long time ago when I used SVN last time but it should have a diff/merge tools. Git handles merging amazingly easy, [resolves conflicts](http://book.git-scm.com/5_advanced_branching_and_merging.html) automatically and forces you to remove unnecessary code by yourself.

But anyway you have to compare code line by line and modify as expected.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can obviously use your source code tool for the code mods that you have done.  If I understand you correctly, it is the database scripts that are causing the greatest issue.

I would either purchase some db comparison tools (thinking Redgate here), write your own db scripts that allow you to compare an 'as is' (your current modified database) with the 'to be' database (problem with this is this is time consuming and doesnt offer any ROI!).

Performing comparisons on database is always 'fun'!  Good luck!